# Django test view fails: (1) unable to logged in a new created user and (2) CBV create view test do not create object in test database

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-class-based-views

I have a Django project and I want to implent unit tests.
I want to test a class based view (CBV) name PatientCreate that need to be authentificated.
It is important to not that the sqlite test dabase is already populated with users (data migration).

In my PatientTestCase class, I start defining setup where is created a new superuser named 'test' and logged in the new created user.
Then, I test if user 'test' is logged in but test fails. If logged in a user already registered in test database (i.e. user named 'admin'), test success.

To test for PatientCreate CBV, I write a post request and test if number of patients increase by one. But this test fails, even if I logged in with 'admin'. It seems that patient is not created in test database.

Note that, response.status_code = 200.

I can not figure out where comes my issue.

**project architecture**

```
- core
   - urls.py
- ecrf
   - urls.py
   - views.py
```

**tests.py**

```
class PatientTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='test', password='test', email='test@test.fr')
        # => print(self.user) return test so user is created
        self.login_success = self.client.login(username='test', password='test')

    def test_new_patient_is_created(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.login_success)  # => return False with 'test' but will success with 'admin'
        patient_site = Site.objects.get(sit_ide=4)
        number_of_patients_before = Patient.objects.count()
        response = self.client.post(reverse('ecrf:patient_create'), {
            'pat': 'TES001',
            'pat_sit': patient_site
        }, follow=True, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE='fr')
        number_of_patients_after = Patient.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(number_of_patients_after,
                         number_of_patients_before + 1)  # => return False
```

**ecrf/views**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    model = Patient
    form_class = PatientForm
    success_message = "Le patient a été créé."

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse("ecrf:index")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.pat_sai_log = self.request.user.username
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I realized that CBV testing is obviously different than FBV.
Below, my solution, hope this help and is correct:

```
class CBVCreateViewTestCase(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='test', password='test', email='test@test.fr')
        self.data= {...}

    def test_object_is_created(self):

        condition_before = ...
        request = RequestFactory().post(reverse('app_name:view_name'), self.data,
                                        follow=True, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE='fr')
        # logged-in user
        request.user = self.user
        
        # call to CBV
        response = CBVCreateView.as_view()(request)
        condition_after = ...

        # Test condition_before and condition_after
```

Dealing with logged-in problem with FBV is that creating superuser using create_superuser() function lead to password not being properly hashed in unitest and I do not know why.

But, testing password of user created in setup method with check_password() method fails. But if I create user using create() method, and set user password 'manually' using set_password() method, it works!